# how to list images from ECR Registry

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I wanted to list images from ECR registry, but getting some error. Can someone provide the solution?

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name <Repository_Name>
```

Got error below

```
An error occurred (RepositoryNotFoundException) when calling the 
ListImages operation: The repository with name '<Repository_Name>' does 
not exist in the registry with id 'ID_Name'
```

Note: I want to list all the images from repository, but I don't want to list the images using filter.

Answer (score 6):

From the error, it seems you insert invalid repository name or you are looking in wrong region

```
aws ecr list-images --repository-name VALID_REPO_NAME --region us-west-2
```

OR you can get all images from all repository using this script.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPO_LIST=$(aws ecr describe-repositories --query "repositories[].repositoryName" --output text --region us-west-2);
for repo in $REPO_LIST; do
    echo "list image for $repo"
        aws ecr list-images --repository-name $repo --region us-west-2
done
```

[aws-cli-cheatsheet](https://github.com/Adiii717/aws-cli-cheatsheet)

Comment: Adiii@ Thanks for your responce. I can able to push the images to the same repository which I mentioned, but unable to list the images using below command.                                                                                   aws ecr list-images --repository-name <ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/<Repo_name> --region us-west-1

Comment: No, the parameter expecting repository name, not the ID, it should be like `stage/nodejs` etc

Comment: it will not contain `12334.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/stage/nodejs`, you just need to pass `stage/nodejs`

Comment: My repository URI is below.                                                                                                                             <Account_ID>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello. Could please tell me what needs to be passed in below command.                                                                                                      aws ecr list-images --repository-name <As per your suggestion> --region us-west-1

Comment: Just pass hello

Comment: can you try the complete script?

Comment: just passing the repo name not working in my case as well

Comment: @asmath can you show your command and make sure you are passing the region?

Comment: @Adiii using this below command
aws ecr list-images --repository-name "demo" --region us-east-1